# Mixing network fiber connectors

Tags: networking, cisco, fiber, sfp

Can I mix fiber connections example below:

MediaConverter(SC)<---(ST)----(panel)--(panel)-----(ST)----(LC)-->SFPportswitch

Comment: Give more details, your question is too short.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but do ensure you're using the same fibre diameters for the full end-to-end run - i.e. if you're using 50/125u OM3/OM4 then use that throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need fiber patch cables with the appropriate ends on them and that match the type of fiber between the panels.